# python logging in crontab not working

Tags: python, django, cron, django-extensions

i have python script in django project

```
  # bar.py
  import logging
  logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
  def run():
      ...some logic...
      logger.info("success")
```

and i want make work this script using django-extesions runscript and crontab

```
  #setting.py
  'handlers': {
       'file': {
           'level': 'DEBUG',
           'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
           'formatter': 'verbose',
           'filename': 'foo.log',
       },
   },
   'loggers': {
       'myApp': {
           'handlers': ['file'],
           'level': 'DEBUG'
       }
    }
```

if i run this script in terminal with django-exteions runscript, i can get foo.log and log message "success"

```
  /path/to/venv/python /path/to/myproject/manage.py runscript bar
```

but run this script with crontab, script is doing very well, but it wasn't make foo.log and write nothing

```
  10 * * * * /path/to/venv/python /path/to/myproject/manage.py runscript bar
```

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using python 2.7?

Comment: no using 3.6 but /path/to/venv/python3 is not working